# Bash scripts don't work. Maybe an EOL issue?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, openwrt, eol

I am facing a problem that is driving me crazy. In the past months I have been developing a project based on a Linux distribution (Openwrt) that has been recently updated. My project has a lot of bash scripts that have always worked fine on my machine. Today I compiled the new release of Openwrt for my machine, I installed bash and the scripts don't work anymore. If I execute my script `./myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
```

I obtain:

```
-ash: ./myscript.sh: not found
```

I noticed two really strange facts that may help you guys understand what is going on:

if I change the first line from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh` the script is executed without errors. However bash seems to be properly installed. Below is the result of  `opkg info | grep -A 6 -i bash`:

```
Package: bash Version: 4.3.39-1 Depends: libc, libncurses Status: install user installed Architecture: ramips_24kec Installed-Time: 1460723598
```

If I open script.sh in notepad, the end of line is CRLF. I learnt to use the EOL conversion tool to convert CRLF to LF. I save the file, I close it. But I don't know why, when I open it again the end of line is still CRLF. It is like if something is keeping my scripts with the incorrect end of line.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

the result of `ldd /bin/bash` is

```
/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x55b9b000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x77d0e000)
        libdl.so.0 => /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x55b9b000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x77ceb000)
        libc.so.0 => /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x55b9b000)
Error relocating /bin/bash: __uClibc_main: symbol not found
Error relocating /bin/bash: fcntl64: symbol not found
Error relocating /bin/bash: __fputc_unlocked: symbol not found
Error relocating /bin/bash: _stdlib_mb_cur_max: symbol not found
Error relocating /bin/bash: __ctype_b: symbol not found
Error relocating /bin/bash: __ctype_tolower: symbol not found
Error relocating /bin/bash: __ctype_toupper: symbol not found
Error relocating /bin/bash: __stdout: symbol not found
```

Comment: Where is bash installed to?

Comment: can you execute `/bin/bash --version`. If not, what is the result of `which bash` which results on my linux to `/usr/bin/bash`! Have you execute permissions on all your scripts? Please add results to your post if possible...

Comment: @ Rowland Shaw: bash is installed in /bin

Comment: @Klaus  /bin/bash --version gives me the same error:
/bin/ash: /bin/bash: not found

Comment: @Klaus which bash result is /bin/bash

Comment: you have to type `which bash`. The which command give you the place where your current shell find bash. As you can't execute /bin/bash you should give /usr/bin/bash a chance :-)

Comment: Suggesting that `bash` is installed as `/bin/sh`, so [bash is operating in POSIX mode](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44839/50240).

Comment: @Davide1991 do `ldd /bin/bash`. The error you see can also come from the dynamic linker due to the missing shared libraries.

Comment: @Klaus when I type `/usr/bin/bash ./myscript.sh` I obtain: `/bin/ash: /usr/bin/bash: not found`

Comment: it hasn't be explicitly mentioned yet, so I'll just point out that the error message is being emitted by `-ash` (not `bash`). (`-` preceding a shell name indicates it is the login shell (I think)). Maybe something has changed about how the SHELL (or maybe PATH) variables are being set after your "upgrade" ;-) ... Good luck.

Comment: @Dummy00001 I edited the question so that I could attach the result of `ldd /bin/bash `

Comment: Did you try to reinstall `bash`?

Comment: what is the result of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` returns nothing

Comment: what is the result of `ls -l /bin/sh`?

Comment: That's weird. Normally I get that for executables of the wrong ELF format. I think maybe that indicates bash was compiled incorrectly? It's a possibility anyway.

Comment: You have two issues here, I guess: `bash` is not installed correctly and you are using `ash` instead of `bash`.

Comment: how can i stop using ash instead of bash? Maybe the fact that bash is not compiled correctly is the point. I just copied and pasted the list of repositories in /etc/opkg.conf from the openwrt website. but I am now understanding that I should have compiled bash together with the operating system. I am now looking inside make menuconfig but I cannot find anything concerning bash

Comment: @nerdbeere `ls -l /bin/sh` gave `lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Apr  9 14:47 /bin/sh -> busybox`

Comment: you could always just try reinstalling bash. use `sudo apt-get purge bash && sudo apt-get install bash`, or if you're using yum I can't help you, or if you're using pacman you don't need my help, or just download the source from their website and compile it yourself. After you've done that, switch shells with `chsh <username> -s /path/to/bash`

Comment: do you mean Windows Notepad? Yes, of course, that will always use and save as CRLF. If you mean notepad++, you may have to turn off the option that is saving your file as windows (CRLF) format or put another way, turn on the option to save as Unix/Linux fmt (LF) ., Good luck.

Comment: By whatever means you installed `bash`, you appear to have ended up with a binary that is incompatible with the underlying system.  Since you describe the `bash` installation as as separate step, that's probably where things went sideways.

Comment: I guess this issue is related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34501165/4950322

Comment: Try an alternative way to reset the CRLF. `dos2unix` of `tr -d "\r"`.

Comment: Whats the result of `ls -l /bin/bash`?

Answer (score 0):

Trying using dos2unix utility to convert your line endings.  When you say Notepad, do you mean Windows notepad?  That probably automatically converts line endings to DOS format...

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, use sh instead of bash

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello"
exit 0
```

Comment: It seems OP wants to use bash though.  I don't see any question answered by your post.

Comment: Hi Frederick, DavideEB wants to run script in openwrt router, and in openwrt bash is not installed. But, you can run script by using sh instead of bash, it will work like a charm.